# download dxf file from website

Tags: html, download, dxf

i have .DXF, .DWG and .PDF files in a folder in my website. I have hyperlinks/anchor tags 
that allow you to download these files by clicking on the link and you get the normal dialogue that asks you to download. It works for PDF and DWG but not for DXF. what could be causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

i added the mime type (application/dxf) to IIS mime types and now the files can be downloaded.